# Proving that if $a$ is an integer and $m_2 n_1-m_1 n_2=1$, then $\gcd(m_1a+n_1,m_2a+n_2)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $m_1$, $m_2$, $n_1$, $n_2$ be integers. We know that $m_2 n_1-m_1 n_2=1$ and need to prove that for $a$ integer:

$$\gcd(m_1a+n_1,\ m_2a+n_2)=1.$$

I tried to prove that using $m_2 n_1-m_1 n_2=1$ we get that $m_2 n_1=m_1 n_2+1$. Then I know that both are consecutive numbers so they are relatively prime and one of them is even and one is odd... I tried to play with this but still don't know how to prove this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\gcd(m_1a-n_1,m_2a-n_2)=b$ then $b$ divides $m_2(m_1a-n_1)-m_1(m_2a-n_2)$.

Comment: why? how did you get this –

Comment: @baaa12: Since $b$ divides $m_1a-n_1$ and $m_2a-n_2$ then $b$ divides their linear combination $m_2(m_1a-n_1)-m_1(m_2a-n_2)$ which equals $m_2n_1-n_1m_2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Use Euclidean algorithm.

$m_1a-n_1= (m_2a-n_2)q+r$

Answer (score 0):

$n_1(m_2a-n_2)-n_2(m_1a-n_1)=-a=1$.

Comment: how???? i typo and this is plus..

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ Invert by Cramer. Below, put $\rm\ \Delta = 1 = b,\ $ so $\rm\,\ gcd(x,y)\mid \color{#C00}{\Delta\, gcd(a,b)} = gcd(a,1) = 1.$

**Lemma** $\rm\quad \begin{bmatrix} m_1 & \rm n_1 \\\\ \rm m_2 & \rm n_2 \end{bmatrix}\ \begin{bmatrix} a \\\\ \rm b \end{bmatrix}\ =\ \begin{bmatrix} x \\\\ \rm y\end{bmatrix}\ \ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \ \begin{array} \!\rm\Delta\  a\   = \ \ \rm \ \ n_2\ x - n_1\, y \\\\  \rm\Delta\ b\ =\ \rm\! {-}m_2\, x + m_1\, y \end{array}\ ,\quad \Delta\ =\ m_1n_2-m_2n_1 $

$\rm\ \Rightarrow\ \ d=gcd(x,y)\mid x,y\ \Rightarrow\ d\mid \Delta\:a,\:\Delta\:b\ \Rightarrow\ d\ |\ gcd(\Delta\:a,\Delta\:b)\, =\, \color{#C00}{\Delta\ gcd(a,b)}.$

Answer (score 0):

I think that seeing as you have shown they are both consecutive integers, you can use the Euclidean algorithm to show

$$\gcd(x + 1, x) = \gcd(x, 1) = 1.$$